# sourcetree has crashed when starting

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I have installed source tree and when I start my terminal I got this error. 
Can anyone got any suggestions?[image]

Here's the info from the log file:

```
2015-07-13T15:02:40: SingleInstance called with arguments:
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
2015-07-13T15:03:07: Could not determine repository from:
'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/rox911/test.git', output was:
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected:
No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey) fatal:
Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
2015-07-13T15:03:23: Fatal error: System.InvalidOperationException:
DialogResult can be set only after Window is created and shown as dialog.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also came across the issue after updating from v1.6.14 to v1.6.16.

Trying to use embedded Git: 
SourceTree >> Tools >> Options >> Git >> Use Embedded Git

**UPDATE**
Issue was fixed in version 1.6.17.0. confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

I used the sourcetree 1.6.16 before. I try several method to solve this problem and failed. 
The solution for me was to use an older version of the sourcetree.
So used sourcetree 1.6.14